# SUM() column based on other columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table with sales plan data for every week, which consists of few columns:

```
SAL_DTDGID -- which is date of every Sunday, for example 20160110, 20160117
SAL_MQuantity --sum of sales plan value
SAL_MQuantityYTD --sum of plans since first day of the year 
SAL_CoreElement --sales plan data for few core elements
SAL_Site --unique identifier of place, where sale has happened
```

How do I sum values in SAL_MQuantityYTD as values of SAL_MQuantity since first records in 2016 to 'now' for every site and every core element?

Every site mentioned in `SAL_Site` has 52 rows corresponding week count in a year along with 5 different `SAL_CoreElement`'s
Example:

```
SAL_DTDGID|SAL_MQuantity|SAL_MQuantityYTD|SAL_CoreElement|SAL_Site
20160110  |20000        |20000           |1              |1234
20160117  |10000        |30000           |1              |1234
20160124  |30000        |60000           |1              |1234
```

If something isn't clear I'll try to explain.

Comment: Your table is not well built. What primary key do you have?
Why do you keep the summed value inside the table where you have the columns you calculate it from?
A rule for databases sais that if you can calculate a value for a column, then your column does not have any point there.

Comment: This table is used to reporting. It's a single fact in warehouse, and all of these data must be located in single table.

Comment: This table might be correct if it is a fact table for analysis services database.

Comment: If so, you can make a `function` or a `stored procedure` to calculate that value whenever you need it.

Comment: Your example is too short for an exact answer and you didn't mention the version of SQL Server that you use, but if you use SQL Server 2012+, you can calculate cumulative sum easily with `SUM(...) OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov unfortunately I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. You are mixing what you have with that you need to obtain. You first say that you have a table with that YTD value, so why do you need to calculate it? Please, post the data as you currently have it and then an example of what you need to get. I think the sample with YTD is what you need to calculate, but it's not clear enough. Also, in your source sample data include several CoreElement and Site different values. Do you need to sum the quantity separatedly for each CoreElement and Site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand your question, but this should allow you to recreate the running sum for SAL_MQuantityYTD. Replace #test with whatever your table/view is called.

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT SUM(SAL_MQuantity)
     FROM #test T2
     WHERE T2.SAL_DTDGID <= T1.SAL_DTDGID
        AND T2.SAL_Site = T1.SAL_Site
        AND T2.SAL_coreElement = T1.SAL_coreElement) AS RunningTotal
FROM #test T1
```

If you wanted to create the yearly figure then you could also use a correlated subquery like this

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT SUM(SAL_MQuantity)
     FROM #test T2
     WHERE cast(left(T2.SAL_DTDGID,4) as integer) = cast(left(T1.SAL_DTDGID,4) as integer)
        AND T2.SAL_Site = T1.SAL_Site
        AND T2.SAL_coreElement = T1.SAL_coreElement) AS RunningTotal
FROM #test T1
```

Edit: Just seen, basically the same answer, using a window function.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you an idea. Please try below.

```
Select A, B, 
(Select SUM(SAL_MQuantity)
   FORM [Your Table] 
   WHERE [your date column] between '20160101' AND '[Present date]') AS SAL_MQuantityYTD 
FROM [Your Table]
```

Comment: This isn't good approach since I'd have to handle [Present date] manually for every 52 rows

Comment: Maybe you should use a stored procedure. Save all the years in a table and do a while end of table. In the loop you can select one year after ankther and sum as per example above

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from your questions is that you want to have the YTD sum of SAL_MQuantity for each year (you can simply 'where' after if you only want 2016), SAL_Site, SAL_CoreElement.

The code below should achieve that and will run on SQL 2008 r2 (im running 2005).

'##t1' is the temp table name I used to test, replace it with your table name.

```
Select distinct 
        sum (SAL_MQuantity) over (partition by 
                                    left (cast (cast (SAL_DTDGID as int) as varchar (8)),4)
                                    , SAL_Site 
                                    , SAL_CoreElement 
                                ) as Sum_SAL_DTDGID 
        ,left (cast (cast (SAL_DTDGID as int) as varchar (8)),4) as Time_Period
        , SAL_Site 
        , SAL_CoreElement
        from ##t1
```